# Footer scrolling with content when viewed on iOS mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, css, footer, sticky-footer

I have a wordpress site which has uses a sticky footer and some jquery to hide and show the tiny nav bar.

When you view the site http://iqonline.eu on an iphone, when you scroll the footer follows the content up the page and then jumps back down to the bottom. Does anyone know how to fix this so it remains at the bottom of the page? Works just fine on all browsers and android devices just iOS.

jQuery code to hide and show the various elements.

```
//showing and hiding the whole footer 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickme").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault() 
        $("#footer").fadeToggle(300);
        $('#menu, #menu2, #menu3, #menu4, #tiny_menu').hide(300);
        $(this).html(($('#clickme').text() == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).attr("title", ($(this).hasClass("active")?"Show":"Hide") + " the menu");
      });
    });

//toggle the tiny menu to show menu items
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery("#tiny_menu").hide();
  jQuery("#menu-button").click(function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault()
    jQuery(this).next("#tiny_menu").slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

tiny menu css

```
.tiny_menu_bar {
    display:none;
    width:524px;
    position: fixed!important;
    bottom: 0px!important;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #e2e2e2; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e2e2e2 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #d1d1d1 51%, #fefefe 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e2e2e2), color-stop(50%,#dbdbdb), color-stop(51%,#d1d1d1), color-stop(100%,#fefefe)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e2e2e2 0%,#dbdbdb 50%,#d1d1d1 51%,#fefefe 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e2e2e2 0%,#dbdbdb 50%,#d1d1d1 51%,#fefefe 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e2e2e2 0%,#dbdbdb 50%,#d1d1d1 51%,#fefefe 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e2e2e2 0%,#dbdbdb 50%,#d1d1d1 51%,#fefefe 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e2e2e2', endColorstr='#fefefe',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

if anyone needs more code just shout.

Comment: Looks like you have : `.tiny_menu_bar {position: fixed!important;} `which is causing that...you have to edit this and you will need to change the styling to get the box to display correctly after that